# How do I reduce number of control plane nodes from 3 to 1?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster installed with kubeadm. Currently it uses a single control plane node. I'm satisfied with this setup in terms of reliability and don't want to turn it into high-available cluster for now. I want to recreate control plane node, so I want to temporary increase control plane nodes to 3, and then to reduce them back to one. How do I do that? I'm afraid that just by turning off and deleting two control plane nodes I'll end up with non-working cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it's enough to remove server from etcd member list. I'm using `kubeadm` and kubeadm can do that. So basically:

`kubeadm reset`
`kubectl delete node control-3`

repeat for second node, keep one node.